# Linux egrep and join

Tags: bash, join, lines

i want to join two fields of stat (date of modify and name) in one line

```
 stat *|egrep  'File|Modifica'

 File: "expresso"
Modifica : 2014-07-21 19:03:53.797915876 +0200
  File: "file"
Modifica : 2014-08-17 02:19:14.116184772 +0200
```

I want output will be

```
 File: "expresso"  Modifica : 2014-07-21 19:03:53.797915876 +0200
 File: "file"      Modifica : 2014-08-17 02:19:14.116184772 +0200
```

I have tried many tr,paste,perl but none work.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want read the manpage of `stat`, to learn about the `-c` or `--format` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Linux:

```
stat -c 'File: %n Modified: %y' t*
```

produces for example

```
File: t Modified: 2014-07-30 09:56:20.000000000 +0200
File: tdir Modified: 2014-08-14 23:40:21.000000000 +0200
File: test Modified: 2014-08-22 14:35:26.000000000 +0200
File: test.xml Modified: 2014-08-03 20:36:42.000000000 +0200
```

and the

```
stat -c 'File: %n Modified: %y' t* | column -t
```

produces lines like:

```
File:  t         Modified:  2014-07-30  09:56:20.000000000  +0200
File:  tdir      Modified:  2014-08-14  23:40:21.000000000  +0200
File:  test      Modified:  2014-08-22  14:35:26.000000000  +0200
File:  test.xml  Modified:  2014-08-03  20:36:42.000000000  +0200
```

on the OS X, the:

```
stat -f 'File: %N Modified: %t%Sm' t* |column -t
```

prints

```
File:  t         Modified:  Jul  30  09:56:20  2014
File:  tdir      Modified:  Aug  14  23:40:21  2014
File:  test      Modified:  Aug  22  14:35:26  2014
File:  test.xml  Modified:  Aug  3   20:36:42  2014
```

Comment: @elbarna Welcome to StackOverflow. The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please see the [Basics of StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Good luck with the answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Through `paste` and `column`,

```
$ paste -d" " - - < file | column -t
File:  "expresso"  Modifica  :  2014-07-21  19:03:53.797915876  +0200
File:  "file"      Modifica  :  2014-08-17  02:19:14.116184772  +0200
```